# Openerp 7: AttributeError: "Field 'name' does not exist in object 'browse_record(wizard_set_ages, 1)'"

Tags: python, odoo, wizard, openerp-7

I've a wizard that needs to take some fields from the module, but when I try to execute this action comes out this error:

```
AttributeError: "Field 'name' does not exist in object 'browse_record(wizard_set_ages, 1)'"
```

the problem is that i don't know how to take the data form the fields. I need to iterate trough all the selected records and do that operation (takes the name an write it in the description in caps lock, like name:Atul -> set_description() -> description: ATUL)
Here's the wizard.py code:

```
from osv import osv, fields

class test_wizard(osv.osv_memory):
    _name='wizard_set_ages'
    _columns={}

    def set_all_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        mystudents = self.pool.get('student.student')
    for student in mystudents.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        my_description = str(student.name).upper()
        mystudents.write(cr, uid, student.id, {'notes' : my_description})

"""edit same for set_all_age        def set_selected_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):         
            my_details = str(prod.name).upper()
        self.write(cr, uid, prod.id, {'notes': my_details }) """
```

and here is the student.py file:

```
from osv import osv, fields


class student_student(osv.osv):
    _name = 'student.student'
    _columns = {
                'name' : fields.char('Student Name', size = 16, required = True, translate = True),
                'age' : fields.integer('Age'),
                'percentage' : fields.float('Percentage', help = 'This field will add average marks of the students out of 100'),
                'gender' : fields.selection([('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female')], 'Gender'),
                'active' : fields.boolean('Active'),
                'notes' : fields.text('Details'),
                }
    _defaults = {
                'name' : 'Atul',
                'active' : True,
                'age' : 13,
                }

    def set_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            dict = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['name'])            
                my_details = str(prod.name).upper()
            self.write(cr, uid, prod.id, {'notes': my_details })
        return True

student_student()
```

---

EDIT: Added wizard_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>        
    <!-- create a view with a unique id -->
        <record id="view_set_all_ages_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">wizard_set_ages_form</field>
            <field name="model">wizard_set_ages</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <!-- create a normal form view, with the fields you've created on your python file -->
                <form string="Set All Student Ages" version="7.0">
                    <group >
                        <separator string="TEST" colspan="2"/>
                        <newline/>
                    </group>
                    <div style="text-align:right">
                        <button icon="gtk-cancel" special="cancel" string="Cancel"/>
                        <button icon="gtk-ok" name="set_all_age" string="Set All Details" type="object" />
            <button icon="gtk-ok" name="set_selected_age" string="Set Only Selected Details" type="object" />
                    </div>

               </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!-- your action window refers to the view_id you've just created -->
        <record id="action_set_all_ages" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Set All Ages</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">wizard_set_ages</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_set_all_ages_wizard"/>
            <field name="target">new</field> 
        </record>

        <act_window id="action_set_all_ages"
                name="Set All Ages"
                res_model="wizard_set_ages" 
        src_model="student.student"
                view_mode="form" 
                target="new"
        key2="client_action_multi"
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: put your xml code also here

Comment: in wizard you add self.write(cr, uid, prod.id, {'notes': my_details }) but there is no field in wizard(wizard_set_ages) you need to use myobj.write(cr, uid, prod.id, {'notes': my_details })  instead of that

Comment: Added the wizard xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will work.

```
def set_all_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        mystudents = self.pool.get('student.student')
        searching_val= mystudents.search(cr, uid, [('id', '!=', ids)])
        for student in mystudents.browse(cr, uid, searching_val, context=context):
            my_description = str(student.name).upper()
            mystudents.write(cr, uid, student.id, {'notes': my_description})

    def set_selected_age(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        mystudents = self.pool.get('student.student')
        data = self.read(cr, uid, ids,)[-1]
        ss = context.get('active_ids') and context.get('active_ids')[0] or False,
        searching_val= mystudents.search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', ss)])
        for student in mystudents.browse(cr, uid, searching_val, context=context):
            my_description = str(student.name).upper()
        mystudents.write(cr, uid, student.id, {'notes': my_description})
```

Put it on your wizard.py

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but if i want to set only the selected student what can i do? I need all the two methods, one for set_all_ages and one for set_selected_ages (only the ages selected in the listview and not the others)

Comment: Nope, it works only for the first selected student and not for the others

Comment: And what is the use of the 'data' variable? Last thing, ss variable ends with "or False," why that ","?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fields in wizard_set_ages but you tried

```
for prod in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):     
            my_details = str(prod.name).upper()
```

Use myobj instead of that( `myobj = self.pool.get('student.student')`) for update and read that table

Comment: So i have to iterate trough myobj instead of self.browse? And for the other function? (set_selected_ages)

Comment: Ok, i've done it, but now it says to me a new error "AttributeError: 'Field name not found in browse_record(student.student, 9)'" I've updated the code on the main question

Answer (score 0):

Going back to your first problem "name does not exist on browse record wizard", there are only two things that trigger this, the model doesn't have a column called name or... you have browsed a non existing record.

However, in your second problem..

Your button is on a form with a backing model of wizard_set_ages which means when the user clicks it, it executes set all age on the wizard_set_ages model.  You then do a self.pool.get on student.student and browse it using the ids argument but here is your problem.  As the form is on the wizard model, the ids argument contains the ids of the wizard model, not the student model so you can't use them to browse the student model.  The usual pattern is to search for the student ids or store them on the wizard when it is created.  Have a look at stock picking wizard for an example of this.